# Regresar valores de una Promise esperando el resultado

Tags: javascript, promesas

Tengo una función que retorna un objeto. El problema es ese resultado proviene de una `Promise`

```js
ready = () => {
   //Declaro mi objeto
   obj = {};
   
   //Preparo la promesa con el resolve
   let promise = new Promise( resolve =>  {
    resolve('WTF')
   });
   
   //Quiero asignar al índice result el valor de la promesa (En este caso WTF)
   obj.result = promise.then( res => {
    if( res === 'WTF' ){
      return res;
   }
   
   })
   
   //Cuando se haya asignado el valor que trae la promesa, entonces regresar el objeto que se declaró arriba
   return obj;
};

//Guardo la información que me regresó mi función
const myResult = ready();

//A este punto yo esperaba ver { "result": "WTF" }
//Y llega así { "result": {} }
console.log(myResult );
```

He intentado declarar la función `ready()` con `async` e invocarla con `await` Pero sigue sin funcionar.

Lo hice así por que la función `ready()` Se invoca desde otro lado, es decir, este código lo necesito para que procese una información y luego regrese un resultado único y continuar con mi `script` fuera de este `scope`

¿Me pueden ayudar a conseguir el objetivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da porque el `resolve` de la `Promise` se ejecuta de forma asíncrona.

### Solución:

En este punto es cuando [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) y [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) pueden ayudarnos a escribir el código como si su ejecución fuera síncrona.

- Definimos a `ready` como una función `async`.
- Esto nos habilitara la posibilidad de usar `await` para esperar el resultado de la `promise`
- Al convertir a `ready` en una [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) podemos usar `.then` para esperar por el valor de está

#### Ejemplo usando `AsyncFunction.then`:

```js
ready = async() => {
  //Declaro mi objeto
  obj = {};

  //Preparo la promesa con el resolve
  let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('WTF');
  });

  //Quiero asignar al índice result el valor de la promesa (En este caso WTF)
  promise.then(res => {
    if (res === 'WTF') res;
  });

  // Esperamos a que se resuelva la promesa
  obj.result = await promise;

  //Cuando se haya asignado el valor que trae la promesa, entonces regresar el objeto que se declaró arriba
  return obj;
};

ready().then((myResult) => {
  //Guardo la información que me regresó mi función
  console.log(myResult);
});
```

#### Ejemplo usando [`IIFE AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
//Async IIFE
(async() => {

  ready = async() => {
    //Declaro mi objeto
    obj = {};

    //Preparo la promesa con el resolve
    let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve('WTF');
    });

    //Quiero asignar al índice result el valor de la promesa (En este caso WTF)
    promise.then(res => {
      if (res === 'WTF') res;
    });

    // Esperamos a que se resuelva la promesa
    obj.result = await promise;

    //Cuando se haya asignado el valor que trae la promesa, entonces regresar el objeto que se declaró arriba
    return obj;
  };

  //Espero y guardo la información que me regresó mi función
  const myResult = await ready()

  // Imprimo el resultado
  console.log(myResult);

})();
```